# c++ vectors erase check

Tags: c++, vector

Is there a way in C++ to check that erase succeeds?
I have two pieces of code that erase the same object. The first erased the object, then the second tries to erase it but doesn't find the object.
Any ideas?

```
for(long indexs=0; indexs < (long)Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.size(); indexs++)
  {
   if((vRegularShots[index].x>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x && vRegularShots[index].y>=Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y && vRegularShots[index].y<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y+17) && vRegularShots[index].x<=(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x+17))||(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x>=vRegularShots[index].x && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y>=vRegularShots[index].y && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].y<=(vRegularShots[index].y+16) && Enemie1.vS2Enemie1[indexs].x<=(vRegularShots[index].x+5)))
   {
    Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS2Enemie1.begin()+indexs);
    vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
    score+=100;
   }
}
```

`vregularshots` holds the shots that were launched and `vS2Enemie1` holds the enemies. if there were two shots that touched the enemy in the same time, then it will loop through the shots and check if it touched any enemies, then erase the enemy and the shot. But when another shot also touched the enemy, it will try to erase the enemy that was already erased.
Any idea ?

---

UPDATE

```
for(long indexs=0; indexs < (long)Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.size();)
  {
   if((vRegularShots[index].x>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x && vRegularShots[index].y>=Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y && vRegularShots[index].y<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y+17) && vRegularShots[index].x<=(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x+17))||(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x>=vRegularShots[index].x && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y>=vRegularShots[index].y && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].y<=(vRegularShots[index].y+16) && Enemie1.vS1Enemie1[indexs].x<=(vRegularShots[index].x+5)))
   {
    Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.erase(Enemie1.vS1Enemie1.begin()+indexs);
    vRegularShots.erase(vRegularShots.begin()+index);
    score+=100;
   }
   else 
    indexs++;
  }
```

Comment: Please provide some example code that demonstrates the question you're having.

Comment: What is a 'script'? C++ code isn't usually called a script, and anyway vectors don't stick around when your program terminates...

Comment: What is a "fist script"?  What does it mean to "earase" something? or "earse"? How do you "lunch" a shot? Who is the "enemie"?

Comment: ok the two codes are the same the only different in the second one the vS1Enemie1 changes to vS2Enemie1.i lunch a shot when the mouse is down and the enemie is some squars

Comment: @abelenky: has it occurred to you that english might no be his first language? For all the words you mentioned, I'm able to gues easily what he meant. So are you. No need to be an ass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really want to use the [Erase-Remove Idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`erase` doesn't fail. If you somehow pass the same parameters to `erase` a second time, then it will try to delete something else. Depending on the exact scenario that might result in it deleting something you didn't intend to, or it might result in corrupting memory and possibly crashing the program if the parameters are no longer valid at all.

However, in the snippet of code you show, I don't see this being problem. Once any enemy is erased from the vector, there is no way the loop would ever encounter it again to even try testing another shot against it.

Though you do have a different problem: When an element is erased from a vector, the indexes of all subsequent elements in the vector are shifted downwards by 1. (If you have 4 elements in a vector, then they would be indexed 0,1,2,3. If you erase the element at index 1, then you'll have 3 elements left with indexes 0,1,2.) The consequence for the code you have is that when an element at `indexs` is erased, another element will shift down to take that place. But the loop just continues and increments `indexs` and so that an element will have been skipped.

Comment: i updated the post but now everytime i shot something and it hit the enemie i get the error again

Comment: well if i don't increments the elmenet it will loop for ever if the if statment equals false

Answer (score 0):

It might happen that you erase several times from `vRegularShots` using the same `index` without checking that the `index` is still in range